# PHP how to extract information from an array within an array?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

First, I would like to mention that I'm terrible at PHP but I'm trying my best to work with it. For some reason I can get information from an array in PHP but I just can't extract information from an array within an array..

So here's the page that var_dumps the array: http://www.farahfa.com/iplanner/webservice/assign_blah.php

And I want to extract all the information in that inner array but I can't figure out how to do it..

Here's my code so far.

```
<?php

include_once "../config/config.php";

// Expected from the app: student_id & assignment_date

$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$assignment_date = $_POST['assignment_date'];

$return=[];

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
        s1.name AS subject,
        a.id AS assignmentID,
        sa.id AS subjectAssignID,
        sa.content AS content,
        sa.due_date AS dueDate,
        a.general_teacher_note AS generalNote,
        sn.note_content AS specificNote,
        sub.isSigned AS isSigned
        FROM student AS s
        LEFT JOIN enrollment AS e ON e.id = e.student_id
        LEFT JOIN classroom AS c ON c.id = e.classroom_id
        LEFT JOIN assignment AS a ON c.id = a.classroom_id
        LEFT JOIN submission AS sub ON a.id = sub.assignment_id
        LEFT JOIN specific_notes AS sn ON a.id = sn.assignment_id
        LEFT JOIN subject_assignment AS sa ON a.id = sa.assignment_id
        LEFT JOIN subject_class AS sc ON sc.id = sa.subject_class_id
        LEFT JOIN subject AS s1 ON s1.id = sc.subject_id
        WHERE e.student_id = 2 AND a.date = '2015-04-07'";

$result = $conn->query($sql); // Execute the query


if ($result->rowCount() >= 1) // If there are data returned then do the following
{ 
    $subject_assignments = $result->fetchAll(); // Get all the rows that are returned
    var_dump($subject_assignments);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($subject_assignments); ++$i )
    {
        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($i); ++$j )
        {
             /*[
                ['subjectAssignID' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['subjectAssignID'],
                'subject' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['subject'],
                'content' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['content'],
                'dueDate' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['dueDate']],
                ['subject' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['subject'],
                'content' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['content'],
                'dueDate' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['dueDate']],
                ['generalNote' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['generalNote'],
                'specificNote' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['specificNote'],
                'assignmentID' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['assignmentID'],
                'isDone' => $subject_assignments[$i][$j]['isDone']]
            ]*/
        }
    }
}

/*
 [
  [
   'subjectAssignID' => '1',
   'subject' => 'subjectHere',
   'content' => '1',
   'dueDate' => 'sdfds'
  ],
  ['subject' => 'subjectHere','content' => '1','duedate' => 'sdfds'],
 ],
 'teacherNote' => 'Whatever',
 'parentNote' => 'Note Parent'
 'assignmentID' => '1'

echo json_encode($return); //Makes it a json array
} else {
    echo 0;
}
*/
?>
```

If anyone can help me with this I'd be eternally thankful!

Comment: The array dump at link shared above is not clearly readable. Can you just echo "<pre>"; just above it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//Lets say your $result looks something like this
$result[]= array("subjectAssignID"=> 111, "isSigned"=> "yes", "assignmentID"=>222,
                "subjectName"=>"subject", "content"=>"test", "dueDate"=>"April",
                "generalNote"=>"general", "specificNote"=>"specific"
);

$file = file_get_contents('json.json');
unset($file);
file_put_contents('json.json', json_encode($result));
unset($result);
```

Then your json file will have this

```
[{"subjectAssignID":111,"isSigned":"yes","assignmentID":222,"subjectName":"subject","content":"test","dueDate":"April","generalNote":"general","specificNote":"specific"}]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your sql commands are correct
I did not check this code but the idea is to use a nested foreach loop

```
<?php

include_once "../config/config.php";

// Expected from the app: student_id & assignment_date
if($_POST['student_id'] && $_POST['assignment_date'])//only except the code if those conditions are true
{

$return=[];

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
        s1.name AS subject,
        a.id AS assignmentID,
        sa.id AS subjectAssignID,
        sa.content AS content,
        sa.due_date AS dueDate,
        a.general_teacher_note AS generalNote,
        sn.note_content AS specificNote,
        sub.isSigned AS isSigned
        FROM student AS s
        LEFT JOIN enrollment AS e ON e.id = e.student_id
        LEFT JOIN classroom AS c ON c.id = e.classroom_id
        LEFT JOIN assignment AS a ON c.id = a.classroom_id
        LEFT JOIN submission AS sub ON a.id = sub.assignment_id
        LEFT JOIN specific_notes AS sn ON a.id = sn.assignment_id
        LEFT JOIN subject_assignment AS sa ON a.id = sa.assignment_id
        LEFT JOIN subject_class AS sc ON sc.id = sa.subject_class_id
        LEFT JOIN subject AS s1 ON s1.id = sc.subject_id
        WHERE e.student_id = 2 AND a.date = '2015-04-07'";

$result = $conn->query($sql); // Execute the query


if ($result->rowCount() >= 1) // If there are data returned then do the following
{ 
    $subject_assignments = $result->fetchAll(); // Get all the rows that are returned
    var_dump($subject_assignments);
    foreach($subject_assinments as $subject )
    {
        foreach($subject as $assinment )
        {
           //put your code here
             echo $assinment;

        }  
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks! And this should work for multiple entries right? Like, right now the page that I linked is only showing 1 "assignment" if there were more "assignments" then it fetch all of them right?

Comment: Hi STIKO, if it's not too much to ask, could you please help me out with one last small issue with the answer that you've provided above. So where it says `echo $assinment`, how can I list the specific things that I need (like how I listed on OP) and then have them converted to JSON, like, I had the `$result=[]` so I can put everything in there and then convert to JSON using `echo json_encode($return);`

I've been trying to figure that part out but I can't seem to get it right!

Comment: And by specific things I mean: the `subjectAssignID`, `isSigned`, `assignmentID`, `subjectName`, `content`, `dueDate`, `generalNote`, `specificNote`. If you can just give me an example of one of them, I can do the rest. xD